# SwiftUI ForEach loop index is always 0

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a ForEach loop:

```
       ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<instance.values.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    ValueView(value: $instance.values[index] )
                        //bookmark set here
                        .disabled(  distributed && (index != 0 && index != instance.values.count - 1 ))
                        .frame(width: 35)
                        .controlSize(.mini)
                        .padding(.horizontal, -4.0)
                }
            }
        }
```

And if var `distributed` is **true** I want to disable all rows except first and last one.
It wouldn't work as expected, all `ValueView` was enabled or disabled.
And now most surprising thing:
I set Breakpoint to print in console `______________index in @index@` and result is:

```
 ______________index in 0
 ______________index in 0
 ______________index in 0
 ______________index in 0
 ______________index in 0
 ______________index in 0
 ______________index in 0
```

What is an `index`? Why It's always `0`? What is really strange, values in `ValueView` are OK.

Comment: maybe your instance.values.count = 1

Comment: How many elements are actually in instance.  It's probably that there is just a single element and the view is getting rendered multiple times so each time it just prints the only element which will have an index of 0.  To check you could add more elements or print another debug message after the loop to show where it finishes.

Comment: I'm very sorry. It was wrong ForEach. Indeed I THIS For Each was always one element. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Index isn't being updated.  With ForEach $0 is the index.  Give this a whirl:

```
  ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<instance.values.count, id: \.self) { 
                        ValueView(value: $instance.values[$0] )
                            //bookmark set here
                            .disabled(  distributed && ($0 != 0 && $0 != instance.values.count - 1 ))
                            .frame(width: 35)
                            .controlSize(.mini)
                            .padding(.horizontal, -4.0)
                    }
                }
            }
```